# Tracking total sold not total supply?

Tags: erc-20, ico, function, presale, totalsupply

I am setting up a pre sale contract, it enables users to purchase the tokens via a prelaunch which they are distributed from the owners (our contract owners) wallet when a user buys them.

How are people providing live time data on their presale/ico website with how many have been sold?

I understand there is a total supply function and I can also create a total sold function which would work by calling the function.

My thought process tho is logging the sale and then outputting the results as a sum.

How do you guys do this?